# How would I uppercase all characters?

Tags: antlr4

I want to uppercase all characters, before the tree checks them. I'm writing a MIPS Assembler, so if someone would write:

```
jal $0000000C
```

It won't match, because I only have 'JAL'. Of course, you simply could put an alternative or the user just uppercases them himself. But that isn't the point here. Let's say you wrote some big code and you mistakenly wrote the last letter, JAl as lowercase. ANTLR4 would give out an error message. So I'm searching for a fast way to uppercase all characters BEFORE ANTLR4 checks them. Because writing each alternative 'JAL'|'JaL'|'jaL'|'jAl'|etc. is just time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
JAL : J A L;

fragment J : [Jj];
fragment A : [Aa];
fragment L : [Ll];
```

Comment: ... or make the parser case-insensitive.

Comment: @BartKiers Well, I've tried to make all letters uppercase (in C#) in the visitor, so I wrote something like: 

    var opcode = context.OPCODE_RTYPE().GetText().ToUpper();

And it obviously doesn't affect the tree itself and so it still errors me.

But this didn't work.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton, I'm not following you. If you define the `jal` identifier in the lexer like I showed you, it will match any of the following: `'JAL'`, `'JaL'`, `'jaL'`, `'jAl'` etc.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton Bart is completely right (rhymes:). Also, first you should determine if you want for your "compiler" to report an error when someone writes "jal" or not. It does not make much sense to allow users to write this although  it's wrong, and that correct it internally to "JAL". That means that users will always write "jal" and it will always work and than what is your request for uppercase good for....